# How do you display a literal {{ in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a template in Angular2 rc 1 where I need to display a chunk of code from a different language.  That language has {{ in it.

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'blue-box',
    template: `
        <div class="blue-box">
            <div class="blue-box-title">{{boxTitle}}</div>
            {{define "bob"}}This is the template bob{{end}}
            <span>
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </span>
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['../css/blue-box.css'],
})
export class BlueBox {

    @Input() boxTitle: string;

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

How do I get the template processor to treat {{ as a literal string instead of the start of a template expression?   The problem occures
at the {{define "bob"}} where I need a literal {{.

The error on the browser (chrome) console is:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'bob' at column 8 in [
        {{define "bob"}}This is the template bob{{end}}
        ] in BlueBox@2:49 ("
    <div class="blue-box">
        <div class="blue-box-title">{{boxTitle}}</div>[ERROR ->]
        {{define "bob"}}This is the template bob{{end}}
        <span>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
 "): BlueBox@2:49
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use **`ngNonBindable`**

example:

```
<div ngNonBindable> {{ I'm inside curly bracket }} </div>
```

**UPDATE**

The above is valid in Anuglar 2, now in Angular 4 there is a class called [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) that can be used for inserting any kind of code inside of your HTML as a text.

You can check this working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PPChFemU6HnXDBQohIsj?p=preview) from [micronyks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40448119/4341572)

Answer (score 1):

ngNonBindable - is not always an option, you have to use extra DOM element and there is actually a better way

### After RC1

In next release there will be a way to customize interpolation regexp https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7417#issuecomment-221761034. It's allready merged and will be available in next release.

### RC1

Right now you can do this. Go to main.ts ( or other file where you do bootstrap ) and add this

```
// some of your imports here
import { Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { Parser, SplitInterpolation } from '@angular/compiler/src/expression_parser/parser';
import { Lexer } from '@angular/compiler/src/expression_parser/lexer';
import { StringWrapper } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang';
import { BaseException } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/exceptions';

class Parser2 extends Parser {
  myInterpolationRegexp = /\[\[([\s\S]*?)\]\]/g; // <- CUSTOMIZATION
  constructor(public _lexer: Lexer) {
    super(_lexer)
  }
  splitInterpolation(input, location):SplitInterpolation {
    var parts = StringWrapper.split(input, this.myInterpolationRegexp);
    if (parts.length <= 1) {
      return null;
    }
    var strings = [];
    var expressions = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      var part: string = parts[i];
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        // fixed string
        strings.push(part);
      } else if (part.trim().length > 0) {
        expressions.push(part);
      } else {
        var exs = `Parser Error: Blank expressions are not allowed in interpolated strings at column ${this._findInterpolationErrorColumn2(parts, i)} in [${input}] in ${location}`;
        throw new BaseException(exs);
      }
    }
    return new SplitInterpolation(strings, expressions);
  }
  private _findInterpolationErrorColumn2(parts: string[], partInErrIdx: number): number {
    var errLocation = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < partInErrIdx; j++) {
      errLocation += j % 2 === 0 ? parts[j] : `{{${parts[j]}}}`;
    }
    return errLocation.length;
  }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  // add your custom providers array with out parser provider
  new Provider(Parser, { useClass: Parser2 })
]);
```

Now you can write your templates like this

```
<div>[[ title ]]</div>
{{begin}} asdas {{#end}}
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of list | isodd">
    [[ item.name ]]
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that now you don't have to wrap your code in NgNonBindable

UPD:

### One of the reasons why ngNonBindable is a bad choice.

This example will be broken in may ways

```
<div>{{ title }}</div>
<div ngNonBindable>
  {{begin}}
  <button (click)="add()">add</button>  <!--- Will Explode!!! --->
  <div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of list | isodd">
      {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{#end}}
</div>
```

If you use InterpolationRegexp - everything will work just fine ( and it's one DIV less )

```
<div>[[ title ]]</div>
{{begin}}
<button (click)="add()">add</button>
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of list | isodd">
    [[ item.name ]]
  </div>
</div>
{{#end}}
```

Comment: "After RC1" The interpolation regexp seems to be a global option. I would not expect that to help in this case when you only want a single binding to be shown raw but the rest of the application to be processed normally.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer plz read the update. I agree that in some small cases ngNonBindable is better. But overall - it's not a very good solution.

Comment: If you want to integrate with another framework that uses `{{}}` then interpolation regexp is certainly the better option. If you have some snippets in an Angular application (like Angular code examples) then `ngNonBindable` is probably the better option. I assume that with non-standard interpolation regexp no component library can be used anymore (like angular2-material) and your whole application needs to be built with `[[]]` (for example) instead of `{{}}`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer good point with component library. Totally agree. Sometimes InterpolationRegexp also can mess you up.