# ngNonBindable not working in angular-2

Tags: angular

I want to display source code using google pretty print inside my app component. I am using ngNonBindable in 'pre' tag. but it give error on compile/page run.

```
zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
<div id="routerContainer">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@37:6
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("
<div id="routerContainer">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@37:6 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
```

My html code is

```
<pre class="prettyprint"  ngNonBindable>
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';                                    
</pre>
```

Comment: why are you using import statement within `pre `tag? `ngNonBindable` tells angular2 not to evaluate any expression or binding.

Comment: @micrnyks, I am displaying the whole .ts source code in my web page.It is for display purpose only not for parsing purpose. Is it a bug with angular2, that it parse {} despite ngNonBindable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check Demo Here : https://plnkr.co/edit/PPChFemU6HnXDBQohIsj?p=preview**

---

To display `.ts` code, You can use **`DomSanitizer`** to display what you want.

```
import {Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <pre [innerHtml]="html">
    </pre>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  html: SafeHtml;
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {

    this.html = `
    import {Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'
    import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:' 
         <span> Angular2 </span>
    '
    })
    `;


    this.html = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.html);
  }

}
```

Comment: `import { DomSanitizer,SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser'` I also updated my plunker. Change it to SafeHtml and import it as shown.

Comment: This doesn't work with `<ng-content>` unfortunately. For example, `<my-code-block>$(() => {});</my-code-block>`