# How can I use the ng-non-bindable directive in an Ionic 2 app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, ionic2

I'm trying to write text which includes single and double braces inside a `<p>` tag. I've tried modifying it to `<p ng-non-bindable>` but the angular compiler still picks up the braces.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute

```
ngNonBindable
```

Possibly duplicate of :

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578200/how-do-you-display-a-literal-in-angular-2/37578771)

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't seem to work. Unless I'm doing it wrong. I just ended up injecting array elements from my constructor function. Which does the trick well. And, using `ngNonBindable` while in Visual Studio Code seems to expect an input since auto-complete turns it into `ngNonBindable=''`.

Comment: Remove the ='' from the attribute